# How to view VSCode and Google Chrome in one screen - MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macos-ventura

I'm trying to work through a tutorial on YouTube (running on Google Chrome) while being able to work through it on VSCode.

It's doable with Sublime Text but VSCode seems to be more powerful.

How do I do it?

I'm running Ventura on MacOS.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to expand this request a little bit.  Just a quick pass and it doesn't make sense what you are asking.

If you are asking how to load/install VSCode for Mac, you can download it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: I want to have half of my screen devoted to VSCode and half to the YouTube video